# How to set the first character via regex?

Tags: c#, regex, url, regex-negation

The first character can be anything except an equals sign (`=`).

I made the following regex:

```
[^=].
```

`ab`, `b2` etc will pass, and `=a` will not.

But the thing is, I also want to accept single character:

`a` should also be accepted. How can I do that?

**Update**

You might wonder why I'm doing it. I have a URL regex

`(?!=)((www\.|(https?|ftp)://)[.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9/_:@=.+?,#%&~-]*[^.'#!()?, ><;])`

but I don't want the URL to be parsed if it's right after the `=` character.

Comment: What language are you using? C#? Ruby?

Comment: Sorry, for not mentioning it, C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!=)
```

`^` matches the start of the input, and `(?!...)` is a negative look ahead. It also matches an empty string.

Comment: How do you know that it is a perl regex that is needed here? :)

Comment: @Benoit, it is a PCRE syntax, so not only supported by Perl. PHP, Java, JavaScript, Python, etc. all support the syntax I posted above.

Comment: I think that's almost what I need. However, "^(?!=)aa" doesn't accept " aa", and I need spaces to be accepted too. So I think that "^" should not be in the RegEx. You might wonder why I'm doing it. I have a URL RegEx, but I don't want the URL to be parsed if it's right after the '=' character.

Comment: @Alex, `^(?!=)aa` only matches strings that start with `aa` (the look ahead isn't even needed in that case). I don't understand why you'd add the `aa` in your regex.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem by modifying your solution a little. Thank you!

Comment: @Alex: I hope one of your modifications was to change the lookahead to a lookbehind.  As Bart observed `(?!=)` is looking at the first character of the URL, when you should be looking at the last character *before* the URL: `(?<!=)`.  (I know it's a little late, but all of the answers are wrong because everyone assumed you were matching the URL as a standalone string, not searching for it within a longer string.)

Answer (score 3):

If this is the only constraint in your regex, you should try to use the API provided by the language you're working with to get the first character of a string.

```
String s = "myString";
if(s.Length == 0 || s[0] != '=')
    //Your code here
```

---

If you really want a regex look at [@Bart solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931992/how-to-set-the-first-character-via-regex/3932011#3932011).

Here is an alternative without look ahead `/^([^=]|$)/`

```
^        <- Starts with
(        <- Start of a group
  [^=]     <- Any char but =
  |        <- Or
  $        <- End of the match
)        <- End of the group
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need RegEx. There is [String.StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx)...

```
if ( ! theString.StartsWith("=") ) {
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Anchor to the beginning and end, and make the whole thing optional.

```
^(?:[^=].*)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use `^=` and act if there is no match in your code?